# Snowflake LISTAGG function creating empty strings instead of nulls

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, listagg

I am using the LISTAGG() function of Snowflake and I noticed that the resulting column does not filter correctly on the condition `col IS NOT NULL` anymore because it interprets all missing values as empty strings, hence `col != ''` seems to be the way to go for me.

As I think it's not clear, is there a way to explicitly and properly create a column with LISTAGG and assign NULL in case the result is an empty string?

So far what I came up with was just something like this, but it's not efficient as I am outputting two columns:

listagg(distinct col3, ', ') AS col1,
IFF(col1 = '', NULL, col1) AS col2

Is there a way to do it in a single row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [NULLIF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif) to replace empty string `''` with NULL:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT NULLIF(col3, ''), ', ') AS col1
```

---

[LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg#returns) by definition skips NULL values:

> Returns a string that includes **all of the non-NULL input values**, separated by the delimiter.